# How can I parallelize Writes to the same row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm currently building a system that does running computations, and every 5 seconds inserts or updates information based on those computations to a few rows in MySQL. I'm working on running this system on a few different servers at once right now with a few agents that are each doing similar processing and then writing on the same set of rows. I already randomize the order in which each agent writes its set of rows, but there's still a lot of deadlock happening. What's the best/fastest way to get through those deadlocks? Should I just rerun the query each time one happens, or do row locks, or something else entirely?

Comment: randomization is not a good way. row-level locks and a central arbitrator that handles assigning rows-to-do would be a better way to go.

Comment: link to info on how to set something like that up?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try something that won't require more than one client to update your 'few rows.'

For example, you could have each agent that produces results do an `INSERT` to a staging table with the MEMORY access method.

Then, every five seconds you can run a MySQL event (a stored procedure within the server) that loops through all the rows in that table, posting their results to your 'few rows' and then deleting them.  If it's important for the rows in your staging table to be processed in order, then you can use an AUTO_INCREMENT id field. But it might not be important for them to be in order.

If you want to get fancier and more scalable than that, you'll need a queue management system like Apache ActiveMQ.